# How to check post type (to include custom css)

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I need to check the post type. If I put this in my functions file:

```
echo "the post type is" . get_post_type();
```

the message just becomes: "the post type is".
Is the post type checked to early? Do have to put it in some action to check for it at a later time?

(Consequently this didn't work:)

```
if (get_post_type() == 'product'){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css_products.css', get_stylesheet_uri().'assets/css/css_products.css', false );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes too early is probably why, the global `$post` variable is not populated yet. Try hooking to a later action (I think `init` at the very least):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_product_styles');
function enqueue_product_styles() {
    if (get_post_type() == 'product'){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'css_products.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/css_products.css', false );
    }
}
```

Comment: That works allright, thanks! I also needed to change to get_stylesheet_directory_uri() (for my child theme directory) , plus add an extra slash before 'assets'.

Comment: ah yep missed those, i'll update the answer too. :)